# How can I format a time duration to a string with localized time units on Android?

Tags: android, time, formatting

I would like to format a time duration (e.g. in seconds) in a String which would contain the localized names of time units. For example for input 8692 I would get string "2 h 24 min 52 sec" with the time units correctly localized for each language. Is there some class in Android that could do this? Does anyone know some external opensource library for this? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by correctly **localized** for each language?

Comment: For example when someone uses the app in China he would see something like 2小时24分52秒 instead of 2 h 24 min 52 sec (which would be good for English users). So basically to use the correct translation of the time units for each user.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime(long) I know this was asked a while ago, but I couldn't find any suitable answers, and that function should do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this same issue when trying to print a Kotlin `Duration` type with **localized formatting** and because I couldn't find a good solution, I **wrote one myself**. It is based on APIs provided starting in Android 9 (for localized units), but with a fallback to English units for lower Android versions so it can be used with lower targeting apps.

Here's how it looks like on the usage side (see Kotlin [Duration](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/) type to understand 1st line):

```kotlin
val duration = 5.days.plus(3.hours).plus(2.minutes).plus(214.milliseconds)

DurationFormat().format(duration) // "5day 3hour 2min"
DurationFormat(Locale.GERMANY).format(duration) // "5T 3Std. 2Min."
DurationFormat(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar").format(duration) // "٥يوم ٣ساعة ٢د"
DurationFormat().format(duration, smallestUnit = DurationFormat.Unit.HOUR) // "5day 3hour"
DurationFormat().format(15.minutes) // "15min"
DurationFormat().format(0.hours) // "0sec"
```

As you can see, you can specify a custom `locale` to the `DurationFormat` type. By default it uses `Locale.getDefault()`. Languages that have different symbols for number than romanic are also supported (via `NumberFormat`). Also, you can specify a custom `smallestUnit`, by default it is set to `SECOND`, so milliseconds will not be shown. Note that any unit with a value of `0` will be ignored and if the entire number is `0`, the smallest unit will be used with the value `0`.

This is the **full `DurationFormat` type**, feel free to copy (also available as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Jeehut/78534c27b24d78f14a3cbd3eebead861) incl. unit tests):

```kotlin
import android.icu.text.MeasureFormat
import android.icu.text.NumberFormat
import android.icu.util.MeasureUnit
import android.os.Build
import java.util.Locale
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.days
import kotlin.time.hours
import kotlin.time.milliseconds
import kotlin.time.minutes
import kotlin.time.seconds

@ExperimentalTime
data class DurationFormat(val locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()) {
    enum class Unit {
        DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLISECOND
    }

    fun format(duration: kotlin.time.Duration, smallestUnit: Unit = Unit.SECOND): String {
        var formattedStringComponents = mutableListOf<String>()
        var remainder = duration

        for (unit in Unit.values()) {
            val component = calculateComponent(unit, remainder)

            remainder = when (unit) {
                Unit.DAY -> remainder - component.days
                Unit.HOUR -> remainder - component.hours
                Unit.MINUTE -> remainder - component.minutes
                Unit.SECOND -> remainder - component.seconds
                Unit.MILLISECOND -> remainder - component.milliseconds
            }

            val unitDisplayName = unitDisplayName(unit)

            if (component > 0) {
                val formattedComponent = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).format(component)
                formattedStringComponents.add("$formattedComponent$unitDisplayName")
            }

            if (unit == smallestUnit) {
                val formattedZero = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).format(0)
                if (formattedStringComponents.isEmpty()) formattedStringComponents.add("$formattedZero$unitDisplayName")
                break
            }
        }

        return formattedStringComponents.joinToString(" ")
    }

    private fun calculateComponent(unit: Unit, remainder: Duration) = when (unit) {
        Unit.DAY -> remainder.inDays.toLong()
        Unit.HOUR -> remainder.inHours.toLong()
        Unit.MINUTE -> remainder.inMinutes.toLong()
        Unit.SECOND -> remainder.inSeconds.toLong()
        Unit.MILLISECOND -> remainder.inMilliseconds.toLong()
    }

    private fun unitDisplayName(unit: Unit) = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val measureFormat = MeasureFormat.getInstance(locale, MeasureFormat.FormatWidth.NARROW)
        when (unit) {
            DurationFormat.Unit.DAY -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.DAY)
            DurationFormat.Unit.HOUR -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.HOUR)
            DurationFormat.Unit.MINUTE -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.MINUTE)
            DurationFormat.Unit.SECOND -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.SECOND)
            DurationFormat.Unit.MILLISECOND -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.MILLISECOND)
        }
    } else {
        when (unit) {
            Unit.DAY -> "day"
            Unit.HOUR -> "hour"
            Unit.MINUTE -> "min"
            Unit.SECOND -> "sec"
            Unit.MILLISECOND -> "msec"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it like that.

```
val minuteString = systemResources.getString(systemResources.getIdentifier("minute", "string", "android"))
val secondString = systemResources.getString(systemResources.getIdentifier("second", "string", "android"))
val hourString = systemResources.getString(systemResources.getIdentifier("hour", "string", "android"))
val dayString = systemResources.getString(systemResources.getIdentifier("day", "string", "android")
```

In this file you look up other time unit resources https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any open source library, but if I understand the problem correctly, it shouldn't be too hard to do it by hand:

```
public static String foo(int duration) {
    int hours = duration/3600;
    int minutes = (duration%3600)/60;
    int seconds = duration%60;
    return hours + getResources().getString(R.string.hours) +
           minutes + getResources().getString(R.string.minutes) +
           seconds + getResources().getString(R.string.seconds);
}
```

Then you define those strings in your `strings.xml` and localise them as you normally would. (See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

As for Android, there's the `Duration` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html), which you could use, but its `toString()` method does not exactly do what you want.

**Edit** just for completeness: I now understand your problem better, you don't want to localise all the time units by hand. Unicode Common Locale Data Repository has some (well, a LOT of) interesting data to offer. They provide XML data on pretty much anything you could possibly want to localise, e.g. `de.xml` (German):

```
<unit type="duration-hour">
    <displayName>Stunden</displayName>
    <unitPattern count="one">{0} Stunde</unitPattern>
    <unitPattern count="other">{0} Stunden</unitPattern>
    <perUnitPattern>{0} pro Stunde</perUnitPattern>
</unit>
```

I assume that this is overkill, but as I said: for completeness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, this is the solution I am currently using, but it requires me translating the units to every possible language and also creating correct plural variants for each language. I was wondering if there is something ready to use.

Comment: I see your problem. The only thing I found was http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/, it allows you to set a locale manually and has 18 already built in.

Comment: Also, Unicode Common Locale Data Repository has some data you could potentially use, but I have never tried that myself: http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/27/

Answer (score 1):

Here is example to get localized second with different Android version using `NumberFormatter` and `MeasureFormat` from @Jeehut answer

On API < 28, I still not found any official way so using `getIdentifier` from @mobo answer

```
fun getLocalizedSecond(context: Context, second: Int, locale: Locale): String {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        NumberFormatter.withLocale(locale).unit(MeasureUnit.SECOND)
            .sign(NumberFormatter.SignDisplay.NEVER)
            .unitWidth(NumberFormatter.UnitWidth.SHORT)
            .format(second).toString()
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        "$second " + MeasureFormat.getInstance(locale, MeasureFormat.FormatWidth.SHORT)
            .getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.SECOND)
    } else {
        try {
            val res = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("second", "string", "android")
            context.resources.getString(res)
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            "$second sec"
        }
    }
}
```